# Different Network Message Structs

Tags: c++, esp32

Let's say I have two types of messages I want to send over a network (in my case ESP-NOW): Config Messages and Actor instruction messages (say: RGB Values for some LEDs).
The receiving end can't know what message type to expect, so i'm looking for a best practice way of doing this.

The Contents of the config message would be something like:

```
typedef struct config_message {
uint8_t address[6];
int counter;
int timestamp;
float sensitivity;
} config_message;
```

the actor data message would be something like:

```
typedef struct actor_message {
int red1;
int green1;
int blue1;
int red2;
int green2;
int blue2;
} actor_message;
```

Now the way I see it, either I create one big message struct that has all variables in them plus a message type:

```
typedef struct message_struct {
int message_type;
uint8_t address[6];
int counter;
int timestamp;
float sensitivity;
int red1;
int green1;
int blue1;
int red2;
int green2;
int blue2;
} message_struct;
```

OR i add a message_type as first int to both structs and then do something like

```
typedef struct message_received { 
int messageType;
} message_received;
message_received messageReceived;
config_message configMessage;
actor_message actorMessage;
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
memcpy(&messageReceived, incomingData, sizeof(messageReceived));
if (messageReceived.messageType == CONFIG) {
   memcpy(&configMessage, incomingData, sizeof(configMessage));
}
else if (messageReceived.messageType == ACTOR) {
   memcpy(&actorMessage, incomingData, sizeof(actorMessage));
}
```

Which somehow also seems dirty to me.
Is there a better way? Or would this be the way to go?

Answer (score 4):

When handling multiple types of messages you'll often want a way to differentiate between them without compromising too much on message size or the complexity of your data parsing logic.

Your suggestions are common practices however here are some considerations and an improved approach:

1. **Unified Message Type Field**: It's essential to have a unified message type field at the start of the message. This ensures that you can always read the message type first, then decide how to process the rest of the message.
2. **Use Unions for Memory Efficiency**: Instead of creating a large structure that encompasses all message types, you can use a combination of structures and unions. A union in C and C++ allows you to use the same memory location for storing different types, but only one at a time. This makes your message structure more memory efficient.
3. **Fixed vs. Variable Length Messages**: If you're sure the message lengths won't change, you can use fixed-length messages. This makes parsing slightly easier, as you always know the length of each message based on its type. However, if you expect the messages to evolve, you might also consider prefixing each message with its length.

Here's an example using a union:

```cpp
#define CONFIG 1
#define ACTOR 2

typedef struct config_message {
    uint8_t address[6];
    int counter;
    int timestamp;
    float sensitivity;
} config_message;

typedef struct actor_message {
    int red1;
    int green1;
    int blue1;
    int red2;
    int green2;
    int blue2;
} actor_message;

typedef struct network_message {
    int message_type; // always the first element
    union { // this union holds space equivalent to the largest member struct
        config_message config;
        actor_message actor;
    } data;
} network_message;

void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
    network_message receivedMessage;
    memcpy(&receivedMessage, incomingData, sizeof(receivedMessage.message_type));

    switch(receivedMessage.message_type) {
        case CONFIG:
            memcpy(&receivedMessage.data.config, incomingData + sizeof(receivedMessage.message_type), sizeof(config_message));
            // you should handle config message here
            break;
        case ACTOR:
            memcpy(&receivedMessage.data.actor, incomingData + sizeof(receivedMessage.message_type), sizeof(actor_message));
            // you should handle config message here
            break;
    }
}
```

This approach minimizes memory usage (only enough memory for the largest message type is reserved) and cleanly separates each message type in the code.

But remember that you must always be aware of not going over array boundaries during `memcpy` operations.